# Alternative to num_rows in Prepared Statements are Unbuffered Query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

MySQLi Prepared Statements are Unbuffered result set by default which means we can not use the `num_rows` unless we explicitly create a buffered result set by using `$stmt->store_result();`.

In my case I just need to use the `$stmt->num_rows` to make sure that there is a result comming from database. so I used something like

```
 if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    while($stmt->fetch())
                {
                 echo  '<li>'.$name.'</li>';
                }
         }else {
                echo "No Such a Data";
               }
```

now my question is if I would not like to change the unbuffured query to buffered one what is the alternative method to check there is a result in the database server?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the returned statement is a resource and then look at the row count, then fetch as appropriate.

```
$stmt = $mysqliObject->query("SELECT * FROM table");

if(is_resource($stmt) && $stmt->num_rows > 0) {
  // we got a result and have data in this table
  while($item = $stmt->fetch()) {
     // $item is our data from this row
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi skrilled, thanks for your comment but I guess you didnt get what I am exactly asking in the post. As I said already I do not want to use the `num_rows` since it required to switch the query result set to be Buffered by using the `$stmt->store_result();`. Now lets say without doing this what is the best way to check if there is any data coming?!

Comment: I guest the way you are doing the code is not getting `Alterantive` method but double checking the existence of resource which is not the answer to my question